# How and where do I start writing my app with Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Google App Engine and I followed all the Quickstart documentation and this is where stand now:

- I created a billing account
- I created a project in the cloud console online
- I installed the SDK and can use `gcloud` via the command line
- I can see the project when I run `gcloud projects list`
- I installed node.js (because I wanted to use the *Standard* platform with it)

and now I don't know what's next. In particular I'm interested in:

- Where do I write my code?

Should I create a folder and put my files there or do I have to *clone* the online project fist, similar to how I would use `git clone <url>` - but I don't see such a command. Is there any other *init* command that would setup all the `*.yml` files necessary for deployment?

- Can I run and debug that application locally, e.g. with `VSCode`?
- I'm going to work with Google Docs - will I be able to open a document and parse it paragraph by paragraph like I would do it with Google Apps Script? Is the [Google APIs Node.js for docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/docs/index.html) the right *tool* for this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Where do I write my code?

You can create a repository at GitHub or GitLab and attach [cloudbuilder](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/) to your repository. That way Google will deploy your changes directly via your repository to your environment ("push-to-deploy").

- Can I run and debug that application locally, e.g. with VSCode?

Yes you can, just use normal environment for your runtime (node.js).

- I'm going to work with Google Docs - will I be able to open a document and parse it paragraph by paragraph like I would do it with Google Apps Script?

Yes but maybe not import the document directly into appengine (or I know no such way) but you can fetch your document via HTTP at least.

Comment: I've just found [Setting up a Node.js development environment](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/setup) so I'll leave this link here too.